# how to stop constructor from over riding in inheritance in java in derived class trying to use private but not working

Tags: java, oop, constructor

**i want no one to override my constructor trying to use private method but it is giving my error how to stop overriding my constructor**

```
 class bc {

  int a;

  bc() {
   System.out.println("hi this is construvtor ");
   a = 10;
   System.out.println("the value of a=" + a);
  }
 }

 class dc extends bc {

  int b;

  dc() {

   a = 20;
   System.out.println("derived dc");
   System.out.println("derived value of a=" + a);
 }

 }
 public class sup {
  public static void main(String[] args)

  {
  dc s1 = new dc();
  }

 }
```

Comment: you're not in including the error, nor showing how you're using a private method.

Comment: A constructor is not overriden ... so this would be complicated. You can overload a constructor. But in a subclass, you need to define the constructor again, and call  `super(...)` based on the "supe" constructor you want to use. But this is not overiding

Comment: Every class can has its own constructor and you can't forbid it. What you can do is not to allow your class being extended by adding `final` to your class definition.

Comment: Never forget that a inheritence still need to instanciate the parent class members, meaning that it required to use a constructor from the parent class. Withtout this, how would you have the parent completly defined ?

Comment: Each of your classes have only one constructor. A subclass constructor **must** call a base class constructor, so having only one constructor means that you cannot block it, because if you did, no one could create a subclass. If that's what you want, make the class `final`, and it cannot be subclassed.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not overriden, methods are.
As you add a constructor in a subclass with the same parameters as which one of the parent class, it doesn't override which one of the parent.
It provides only a way to instantiate the subclass in the same way that the parent class constructor is invoked.

Using `private` constructor in the parent class will just make the class not inheritable as a child class constructor needs to invoke the parent constructor and the `private` constructor in the parent class prevents it.

Comment: I would add that if we set every constructors to `private`, we can set the class to `final` to inform directly that the class can't be inherited. That doesn't add much but ...

Comment: @AxelH In the most of case, it is right and it makes things clearer. Good point. Note that you have a corner case : you can still make the class no `final` to create anonymous class of it from the class itself.

Comment: Indeed, good point ! The class could be seen as _effectively final_, even if I don't like that term (I found it too be a lazy "feature" ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can't be overridden because they are not member of class. Sub class constructor invokes super class default constructor by default. If you don't want it to be invoked, then you can make a parameterized constructor in super class and call it in subclass constructor.

```
  class bc {
      int a;
      bc() {
         System.out.println("hi this is construvtor ");
         a = 10;
         System.out.println("the value of a=" + a);
      }
      bc(int i){}
  }

  class dc extends bc {

     int b;
     dc() {
         super(1); // invoking super class parameterized constructor
         a = 20;
         System.out.println("derived dc");
         System.out.println("derived value of a=" + a);
   }

 }
 public class sup {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     dc s1 = new dc();
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that constructors are not overridden. But I wold like to add up some info according to your query.
You can make a constructor of the parent class private only if you have another constructor on the parent class with non-private specifier and in that case you have to call that non private super class constructor from the child class constructor using `super`.

**N.B.:** ***Although there is no practical use case in doing such thing. Just for the sake of your query of `private` `constructor`. Try below code:***

```
    class bc {

    int a;

    private bc() {
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }
    private bc(int s){
        System.out.println("write logic");
    }
    bc(int a,int b){
        System.out.println("***************");
    }
}

class dc extends bc {

    int b;

    dc(int a) {
        super(8,9);
    }

}

public class sup {
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        new dc(9);
    }

}
```